# How far can mobs see?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How far can mobs see?

I know if I have my render distance set to far then I can see mobs before they see me.  Does anyone know precisely how far a mob can see?

This would be really nice to know since I could simply make sure there is water around my island that goes further than mobs can see.

Comment: At the very least, ghasts have a longer range, I think.

Comment: On a side note I do know that mobs will not spawn within 24 blocks of the player.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't an answer on some forum post somewhere...bounty time!

Comment: @ Ben Kennett: Except in a monster dungeon.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here is the relevant piece of code from the Minecraft source:

```
EntityPlayer entityplayer = worldObj.getClosestPlayerToEntity(this, 16D);
        if(entityplayer != null && canEntityBeSeen(entityplayer))
```

This means that the range of sight is 16 blocks; however, there's also something funny. For one, if there is a closer player than you, but they can't be seen (for example, if the closer player is behind a wall), then the mob won't notice you.

Additionally, the ghast uses a separate method including:

```
worldObj.getClosestPlayerToEntity(this, 100D);
```

So it will see you 100 blocks away.

Comment: Awesome, glad to see my digging was correct at least

Comment: Nice source code digging!

Comment: @Not a Name Where did you get the source code?

Comment: I am guessing this is no longer accurate for zombies?  I can see them running at me from a long distance away.

Comment: @Zoredache I'm not sure when this was added, but zombies do have the ability to alert other nearby zombies when they detect you, so it might be that happening.

Comment: Is this answer still accurate at 1.7.10? So no mob may be alerted from further than 16 blocks unless mods come in power?

Answer (score 11):

This isn't the best evidence I've ever dragged from the interwebs, but here is what my searching on the minecraft forums has found.

Mobs seem to have an awareness extending 16 blocks.

I never did find this factoid spelled out specifically but I did find these posts referencing it:

- "The only change to line of sight is increasing from 16 to 32?"

  - http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=96258#p1481390
- "Standard 16 block awareness range"

  - http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=86872
- 16 blocks is referenced as aggro radius

  - http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=76554

From the numerous threads I've been reading (and my own experience) the mobs also don't rely on sight. So if you are digging in a tunnel next to a hostile cave the mob knows you are there.

Comment: but they won't attack if they don't see you, they only know that your there.

Comment: @Thomqa True, that's why you get the creeper bounce next to glass panes (I think)

Answer (score 8):

All have 16 blocks line of sight, except the Enderman, which has 64 blocks, and Ghasts, this time 100.

Comment: Hi @AgentClover1, and welcome to Arqade!  Your answer provides the same basic information that the accepted answer provides, but with less detail.  In this case, we would encourage you to edit an existing answer to provide more detail.

Comment: @MBraedley He did add the Endermen thing...