# If I hear a mob in Minecraft, how far away could it be?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I hear a skeleton, or a zombie, how far away could he be? Obviously he can be right next to me, but what is the largest possible range?

Comment: He COULD be right next to you, perhaps underground or a nearby wall.

Comment: Quick, turn around!  A zombie is about to eat your brains!

Comment: Recently, I heard the thwak sound of a slime while heading up my staircase from bedrock, I think there's a cavern nearby that I haven't found yet.  Next thing I knew, it glitched its way through the wall where ever it was and was right behind me.  I hate giant slimes :(

Comment: If it's a creeper, it's too late. Sssssssssssssss....

Comment: Most of the time, they'll emit sounds when they are in the range they start attacking you. Wich mean, they are at most at 16 blocks from you. Doesn't apply to ghosts, wich are long-ranged monsters. You should look at [this thread](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17279/how-far-can-mobs-see).

Comment: After large amounts of digging, I was unable to find the answer. The code from the relevant area is not deobfuscated. ._.

Comment: Haha, you sure love your source digging @Not a Name. :)

Answer (score 41):

I've done some testing, and it seems that it is 16 blocks, from the mob's head to yours. I tested by encasing a pig with dirt, but I assume that it's the same for all mobs. Except Ghasts, that is. It's definitely longer there, probably 100 blocks.

BTW, yes, the pig is perfectly fine except for the time I accidentally hit him, and the time that he got shot by a skeleton.

Comment: It seems they emits sounds only when you are in their aggro sphere, which is 16blocks wide. Don't remember the exact value for ghosts, but i believe it's 120/150 blocks.

Comment: @Lysarion Yeah, that's what I assumed and then tried to imply. It's not just their sight range though, since your head is what "receives" the sound. Ghasts (with an 'a') can see for 100 blocks. You even linked to [Not a Name's awesome answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17279/how-far-can-mobs-see/17443#17443), and that's why I assumed that in mine.

Comment: Also, it is very hard to hear something 15.5 blocks away, so you still might not hear things even when they are making noise.

Comment: 16 / 100 would match the visibility numbers to boot.

Comment: Gasts don't have a limit to their sound range. they make sound and aslong as they don't despawn it's gonna keep playing. (making it probebly 128 blocks at which they instandly despawn)

Answer (score 2):

I have confirmed by putting a lot of **zombies and skeletons** in one hole, that the maximum hearable distance as of Minecraft 1.18 for those mobs is exactly **16 blocks** from the center of the mob indeed.

By spawning a non-moving **ghast** (`/summon minecraft:ghast ~ ~ ~ {NoAI:1}`) I also found that the exact distance for them is **80 blocks**.

What's worth noting is that the hearable zone is a sphere with a radius of 16, and not a cube.

I confirmed that this is correct by using the in-game subtitles feature, that shows a subtitle even for the most silent sounds.

Answer (score 1):

I built A chicken farm once, and I put it outside of the audible zone of the player (Because chicken farms are loud and quite obnoxious)! Anyway, I did a little experimentation with the project, and discovered that Minecraft player's audible zone of hearing, is 24 or more blocks away from you.

Comment: This conflicts with the other answer, which says it is 16 blocks. Can you provide a source for your number of 24?

Answer (score -1):

it can depend. mobzilla from orespawn can probably be heard from 200+ blocks away. I think that in a mod called the john mod, the mega john can be heard from over 500 blocks away. it depends on how loud the mob is, and what your device's volume is on. (note: i don't own either of the before mentioned mods)

Comment: Why did you comment about those mods if you didn't already own them?

Comment: just giving examples, that's all.

Comment: The OP was asking about vanilla Minecraft, they never mentioned mods at all, so this is fully irrelevant

Comment: It is relevant though. Those mobs can be heard from far away, so, like the first thing I said, it can depend.