# What is a snow golem's range?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to incorporate snow golems into my mob grinders.  How close does a hostile mob need to be  in order for a snow golem to begin throwing snowballs?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tested this by making a hall in creative mode and blocking a zombie in a small chamber on one end and letting a snow golem go on the other. He ran forward until he was **10 blocks away** and started pelting the zombie with snowballs until I quit the game.

[image: an unaware zombie being pelted by a loyal test subject]

For those that aren't clear, here's how I counted:

`[G][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][-][Z]`
`[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]`

Their sight seems to be 16, [the same as most mobs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17279/how-far-can-mobs-see). I made one 18 blocks away, and he couldn't see the zombie from there.

Comment: +1: This answer could only be better if you checker-boarded the hallway for an accurate visual measure by readers, if only to confirm whether you included the square the golem was standing on. :)