# How far can wolves detect skeletons in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was reading [How far can mobs see?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17279/how-far-can-mobs-see), and I'm wondering about the aggro range for tamed wolves against skeletons.

I know for certain that wolves do not have the restriction of having to be able to see the skeleton in the manner that hostile mobs must see a player, because my wolves are constantly trying to get to skeletons that they cannot see (when I walk by my skeleton spawner farm, they keep trying to get into the spawn room, which is sealed off).  So, I'm wondering if their aggro distance is also different from the standard 16 block range for hostile mobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that afects this is this attribute: `generic.followRange`.

According to [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Attribute):

> The range in blocks within which a mob with this attribute will target
> players or other mobs to track. Exiting this range will cause the mob
> to cease following the player/mob. Actual value used by most mobs is
> 16; for zombies it is 40.

According to inspecting NBT tag of wolf (also tamed one), wolves do have this value as 16, if not changed by anything. Also tests do show that wolves do start attacking when skeleton gets into sphere area with range of something around 16 blocks or slightly lower(sometimes it is not at the first tick or so).

IF you have spigot-like server, it can be affected by settings in `spigot.yml`, where you can redefine the `entity-tracking-range` , so making it higher or lower. Also specially summoned or modified wolf can have it changed.

So, by default their aggro should be same - 16 blocks range.

Comment: Very good to know about the spigot part - I am indeed on a spigot server - thanks!

Comment: @childofsoong Do notice, that this spigot settings can have real performance effect on your server! Making tracking-range bigger means that every entity scans more area around it EVERY TICK, thus it needs more computer resources. And vice versa, lowering it can make your server run smoother, and with small changes players don't need to notice game change.